# How to read each line of a textfile into a 2D array in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a login system in Java and I have saved admin information in a text file in this format:

```
Hannah,Joshua,Female,373ac,admin123

Leena,Kevin,Female,3283c,admin123
```

The fourth index (`373ac`) is their username and fifth (`admin123`) is the password. Each admin will get a new username and a separate line in the file.

Each time an admin logs in, they will input their name and the program should search through the file with the line that starts with their name and compare the username and password, so they can log in. I think the best way is a 2D array. I have this code so far but it's not reading it as a 2D array but just one array with all the lines. Like this:

```
[Hannah,Joshua,Female,373ac,admin123,Leena,Kevin,Female,3283c,admin123]
```

Can you please help me out?

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Admin.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> listofLines = new ArrayList<>();

        String line = bufReader.readLine();
        while (null != (line = in.readLine())) {
            listofLines.add(line);
        }

        bufReader.close();

        int [][] map = new int[bufReader.size()][];
        int q = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; q++) {
            String[] rooms = bufReader.get(i).split(",");
            map[i] = new int[rooms.length];
            
            for (int w = 0; w < rooms.length; w++) {
                map[q][w] = Integer.parseInt(rooms[w]);
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map[q]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some more details on the "one array" that your code is producing?

Comment: I have made the changes @mmartinez04

Comment: where is the "in" variable declared in the " in.readLine()" line inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Files.lines()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) to read the file as a `Stream<String>`.

```
static String[][] readFileAs2DArray(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Path.of(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        return stream
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[][] result = readFileAs2DArray("Admin.txt");

    for (String[] line : result)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
}
```

output:

```
[Hannah, Joshua, Female, 373ac, admin123]
[Leena, Kevin, Female, 3283c, admin123]
```

Comment: Is there a way to access only 373ac?

Comment: @HannahJoshua You can access `373ac` with `result[0][3]`.

Comment: I have another doubt which is part of the main question. When a user inputs their name i want the program to read only that line of the file and read the 3rd index. How is that possible?

Comment: You cannot `read only that line of the file`. Other options are (1) you read all lines first and search from there. (2) you store it in a database and search from there;

Answer (score 1):

You're populating `listofLines` but never using it

Instead of iterating based on `bufReader`, why not utilize `listofLines`?

Also, why are you using both `i` and `q` as indexes? One seems sufficient

Edit: The `int[][]` array should also be `String[][]`

```
String [][] map = new String[listofLines.size()][];

for (int i = 0;i<map.length;i++){

    String[] rooms = listofLines.get(i).split(",");
    map[i] = new int[rooms.length];
        
    for(int w = 0; w<rooms.length;w++){
        map[i][w] = rooms[w];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map[i]));
}
```

Also, if you want to make your code more succinct

```
String [][] map = new String[listofLines.size()][];

for (int i = 0;i<map.length;i++){

    map[i] = listofLines.get(i).split(",");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map[i]));
}
```

For your `bufReader` try changing the code to this

```
String line = bufReader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    listofLines.add(line);
    line = bufReader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the "cannot find symbol" error for listOfLines. How can I fix that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I had wrote listOfLines, but you have it declared as listofLines, just fixed it

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Leena"----I am getting this error

Comment: I have solved the readLine error. Thank you

Comment: Im not sure why youre using an integer array. You should be using a String[][] array instead, and get rid of the Integer.parseInt(rooms[w]) and simply use rooms[w]

Comment: I'm Sorry I am a beginner to Java and just fixed that but now only the second line of the text file is being printed

Comment: Is there a way both lines can be printed like `[[Hannah,Joshua,Female,373ac,admin123],[Leena,Kevin,Female,3283c,admin123]]`

Comment: yeah delete the `System.out.println` statement in the `for` loop, and instead place `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(map))` after closing the `for` loop

Comment: I am still getting only the second line of the text file

Comment: Try using the code i provided at the bottom of my answer

Comment: So suppose I just want to print out Hannah, how can I do that?